# I get a debug error when using scanf function from Runtime Library

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am simply trying to get an string input and ouput this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
int main()
{
    char x[10];
    scanf("%s", &x);
    printf("%s", x);
}
```

When I input really short word like "info" or something but with "information", it produces debug errors.

I extended char x[10000] but it is all the same. what's the problem with this?

[image]

Comment: The `scanf("%s", &x);` should be `scanf("%9s", x);` (two changes). Note that `"information"` won't fit that string length, and you suffer from buffer overflow. It would need `char x[12]` to hold it, and `scanf("%11s", x);`

Comment: Count the number of letters. "Information" has 11, plus a NUL terminator. How does that fit an unrestricted buffer space of `10`?

Comment: @WeatherVane Very thank you for the comment. I wonder why only extending x[10] to x[100] does not work? Should I fix the format like "99%s" everytime I use scanf with string?

Comment: Yes, and you have copied it incorrectly. It should be `"%99s"` not `"99%s"`, Be careful, in C the tiniest detail matters. But I can't tell you why code you haven't posted does not work.

Comment: @WeatherVane Even I made a mistake with the copy. I wonder why without the format fix  I do not have an error with short word like "info" with only "%s" not "%99s"

Comment: Because `"Info"` is only 4 letters plus the terminator, and the buffer is 10, so there is no overflow. In this case the length restriction didn't make any difference. But you must use the length restriction, because you cannot know what the user will enter.

Comment: @WeatherVane Understood very well. Only the matter was the buffer overflow.

Comment: Yes, and the error message indicated that with "Stack around the variable `x` was corrupted." That variable is on the stack.